# What gcloud command would identify the VM instances in a project which have full access to all APIs?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I want to ensure that all VMs that are running with the default Compute Engine Service Account have their API access locked down hence why I am interested in filtering a gcloud command to identify any non compliant instances however I'm struggling to figure it out the right command.

I know I will need to include AND in the final command to filter on the VMS that are configured to run with the default Compute Engine Service Account VMs but for now I'd like to get the scope filter right!

Based on Google's documentation referring to filtering MachineType [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/compute/instances/list) I thought that filtering on scopes would work after identifying from the REST VM details that the URL that is configured for the *Full Access to Cloud APIs* scope is https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform

I have tried these commands but none have given me a list of the VMs that are configured with the scope **Allow full access to all Cloud APIs**

```
gcloud compute instances list --filter='Allow full access to all Cloud APIs'

gcloud compute instances list --filter="scopes:[https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform]"
```

Anyone know what the command should be?

Comment: You will need to create a list of instances first, then use `gcloud compute instances describe <NAME>` and filter the output on `serviceAccounts[].scopes`. I prefer to use `jq` instead of gcloud filter statements. However, this method by itself will not identify what you want. You will also need to check the roles assigned to the service account. Filter on `serviceAccounts[].email` and then process the roles assigned to the service account using `gcloud projects get-iam-policy ...` Personally I would write a Python script to do all of this.

Answer (score 1):

The scopes are listed under the `serviceAccounts` key per account. Usually, there is just one service account per instance. You can filter on the scopes list of the first service account like:

```
gcloud compute instances list --filter="serviceAccounts[0].scopes:(cloud-platform)"
```

I don't have any multi-account instances but in theory the filter for all accounts would be:

```
gcloud compute instances list --filter="serviceAccounts[].scopes:(cloud-platform)"
```